# How to reduce fusion donut2d chart slice thickness?

Tags: javascript, html, fusioncharts

I am trying to reduce fusion donut2d chart slice thickness. check below image, i have reduce the thickness of green slice mannually, but i want to do it in pragmatically for all slice.

- So is there any json key for donut2d chart slice thickness reduce ?
- is it possible in Fusionchart ? if yes then please guide me.

[image]

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My first chart using FusionCharts Suite XT</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusioncharts.theme.fint.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  FusionCharts.ready(function(){
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        "type": "doughnut2d",
        "renderAt": "chartContainer",
        "width": '450',
        "height": '450',
        "dataFormat": "json",
        "dataSource":  {
          "chart": {
                "caption": "Split of Revenue by Product Categories",
                "subCaption": "Last year",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "use3DLighting": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                "startingAngle": "310",
                "showPlotBorder": "1",
                "showLabels": "0",
                "showPercentValues": "1",
                "showLegend": "1",
                "legendShadow": "30",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "defaultCenterLabel": "Total revenue: $64.08K",
                "centerLabel": "Revenue from $label: $value",
                "centerLabelBold": "1",
                "showTooltip": "0",
                "decimals": "1",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0"
            },
         "data": [
                {
                    "label": "Food",
                    "value": "12"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Apparels",
                    "value": "10"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Electronics",
                    "value": "20"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Household",
                    "value": "8"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Test",
                    "value": "5"
                }
            ]
      }

  });
revenueChart.render();
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="chartContainer">FusionCharts XT will load here!</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually the inner radius of Doughnut can be controlled with the attribute "doughnutRadius".

```
doughnutRadius : Number [-]
This attribute lets you explicitly set the inner radius of the chart. FusionCharts XT automatically calculates the best fit radius for the chart. This attribute is useful if you want to enforce one of your own values.

Range: In Pixels
```

Here is a [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9zck83yL/) to the solution of your problem.

Please let me know if you have any further concerns.
Thank You!

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function () {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'doughnut2d',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '450',
        height: '450',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Split of Revenue by Product Categories",
                "subCaption": "Last year",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500,#f45b00,#8e0000",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "showBorder": "0",
                "use3DLighting": "0",
                "showShadow": "0",
                "enableSmartLabels": "0",
                "startingAngle": "310",
                "showLabels": "0",
                "showPercentValues": "1",
                "showLegend": "1",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "defaultCenterLabel": "Total revenue: $64.08K",
                "centerLabel": "Revenue from $label: $value",
                "centerLabelBold": "1",
                "showTooltip": "0",
                "decimals": "0",
                "captionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "doughnutRadius": "100"
            },
            "data": [
                {
                    "label": "Food",
                    "value": "28504"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Apparels",
                    "value": "14633"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Electronics",
                    "value": "10507"
                }, 
                {
                    "label": "Household",
                    "value": "4910"
                }
            ]
        }
    }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="http://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<!-- Doughnut chart example with: 
# Center label in 2D chart 
# Disabled tool-tips are disabled, but extended center label info on hover

-->
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To customize the inner radius of the doughnut chart, set the value of doughnutRadius attribute in percent

```
{
      "chart": {
        "doughnutRadius": "80"
      }
    }
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/standard-charts/pie-and-doughnut-charts#set-the-radius-as-a-percent-value

Refer to the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/c24e59hm/1/